# Filtering in stacked bar chart using d3 v3.js by changing data on input selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am new to D3 and created stacked bar chart as in http://www.adeveloperdiary.com/d3-js/create-stacked-bar-chart-using-d3-js/.

Assume I use CSV like

```
month,A,B
Jan,10,20
Feb,30,40
```

I need to add filter such that, when input is A, only rectangle with data of A should be visible.Please help me out on how it could be achieved.
I added a specific method with var input="A" and added method as below

```
 var dd=function(x)
{
   if(input==null)
   {
      return direction.map(function (c) {

    return data.map(function (d) {

        //console.log(d[c]);
             return {x: d.month, y: d[c]};
         })    
     })
     }

        else{
             return data.map(function (d) {
               return {x: d.month , y : d[input]};
           });
        }

}
var dataIntermediate=dd(input);
console.log(JSON.stringify(dataIntermediate));
```

This was able to fetch x and y specific to each input, But, when I add it to

```
var dataStackLayout = d3.layout.stack()(dataintermediate);
```

I get t.map is not a function. when it is specific to month and just one input set of value.Flaw is in this code

```
var dataStackLayout = d3.layout.stack()(dataIntermediate);

x.domain(dataStackLayout[0].map(function (d) {
    return d.x;
}));

y.domain([0,
    d3.max(dataStackLayout[dataStackLayout.length - 1],
            function (d) { return d.y0 + d.y;})
    ])
  .nice();
```

At the same time, all data to be visible at the beginning and only after selection, visual need to be filtered.
 I am stuck. Please favour

Answer (score 1):

Just one alteration was needed to be done.

```
var dataStackLayout = d3.layout.stack()([dataIntermediate]);
```

This serves the purpose.That's it.